# Drupal Leaflet dynamic icons/multiple layers

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, leaflet

I have a situation where I need to display content with different terms on a Leaflet map. These terms also are associated with images. At this point, I would like to ask you whether the below can be done.

1) Multiple layers: To show different images, I might need to have multiple layers. Is this possible?

2) Dynamic icons: Is this possible, either with token or something else?

Regards,
mto

Comment: I got it guys. All I needed to do was to set _sites/example.com/files/[node:field_type].png_ as point icon in the map settings, then rename the icon file accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, multiple layers with Leaflet isn't possible at the moment.

However, if you're wanting to differentiate between items of the same type but with different taxonomy tags, the module "IP Geolocation Views and Maps" (https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) will allow you to do this.  They've got excellent instructions and I can vouch for it working.

It can get confused if an item is tagged with 2 of the things you're wanting to differentiate between...